# Visual Studio Intellisense for Custom javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, intellisense

I've create a custom functions in JavaScript for ease coding cause its too repetitive to type those function again and again.

What I do is I created an external JavaScript and linked it to my `_Layout.cshtml`. I've successfully called them without any problem but what I wanted now is to have those custom function to have intellisense.

**global_functions.js**

```
function ZeroPrefixFormat(str, len) {
     str = str.toString();
     return str.length < len ? ZeroPrefixFormat("0" + str, len) : str;
     // OUTPUT : 10 -> 00010 (DIFFERS FROM THE GIVEN LENGTH)
}

function MoneyFormat(amount) {
     amount = amount.toString();
     return Number(amount).toLocaleString('en');
     // RETURN raw number to money format example. 123456789.10 -> 123,456,789.10
}
```

**custom.cshtml**

```
<script>
 console.log(MoneyFormat(123456789));
<script>
```

So when I try to type **Money** it shows intellisense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include Intellisense in following two ways,

1. Add a JavaScript file to the global Visual Studio references
2. Add the reference directly to the top of the Javascript file

**Add a .js file to the global references**

Add a reference to the `JS` file in `Tools -> Options` like this,

Make sure to chose Implicit (Web) in the Reference Group dropdown. Otherwise it won't take effect for web projects.

[image]

Reference Link: http://madskristensen.net/post/improved-javascript-intellisense-in-visual-studio

**Add the reference directly to the top of the `.js` file**

You can add the reference directly to the top of the Javascript file with the relative path as below.

```
/// <reference path="../scripts/jaydata.js" />
```

Comment: Perfect! It works.  Can I verify something? We use Team foundation, will it also affect them?

Comment: No, it wont affect.

Comment: Well that's too bad but Thank you again

Comment: This is a visual studio user settings :-)